# Save selected items from jlist to string variables

Tags: java, jlist

I have a Jlist with 10 items (booktitles).  The user will be allowed to select 3 items out of the 10.  I want to save the selected items to 3 different string variables (example book0, book1, book2, etc).

I am not sure how to do this.

I have the Jlist created with 10 titles showing, and I have tried so many things but no luck.

Comment: Where is the code that failed? Have you looked at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

say for example you have already defined a JList object `list`.

This should do it for you

```
Object[] selected = list.getSelectedValues();

String[] selectedItems = new String[selected.length];

for(int i=0; i<selected.length;i++){

selectedItems[i] = selected[i].toString();

}
```

the array of String `selectedItem` is all you needed, you may also use an arrayList here.

Comment: Thank you, it worked when I implemented the following code:

 Object[] selected= blist.getSelectedValues();

String[] selectedItems = new String [selected.length];
       
for(int i=0; i<selected.length;i++){

 selectedItems[i] = selected[i].toString();

       }

Comment: I am still a java newb and don't really understand how I can use "Object[]" array.  It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Evey class in java has a superclass by default which is the Object class. When ever you create an object of some type say for example you created an object emp of class Employee, this object can also be referenced by a reference of type Object please read Oracle docs. These things come from practice and experience. I would suggest you to read "Head first Java" for easy understanding :)